# Laravel Upload image by excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5

Hello friends i want to upload students data by excel in laravel with laravel excel plugin and i want to uploade image with excel file (By local path or other)
Please suggest me solution for this

i create a function which upload file on my local server but not working on server

```
$excel = Excel::load(Input::file('file'))->get();
        foreach($excel as $exc) {
            $data = $exc->all();
            $data['class_id'] = $id;
            $data['school_id'] = $class->school_id;
            if ($student = Student::firstOrCreate($data)) {
                if (File::exists($exc->image)) {
                    $destinationPath = 'uploads/schools/' . $class->school_id . '/' . $class->id . '/' . $student->id . '/'; // upload path
                    if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
                        mkdir($destinationPath, 0755, true);
                    }
                    $file  = file_get_contents($exc->image);
                    $fileName = str_slug(Carbon::now()->toDayDateTimeString()) . rand(11111, 99999) . '.jpg'; // renameing image
                    if(file_put_contents($destinationPath.$fileName,$file)) {
                        $student->image = $destinationPath . $fileName;
                        $student->update();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Check this link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/insert-image-with-laravel-excel

Comment: i want to upload image on server by local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objphpexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("MyExcelFile.xls");

foreach ($objphpexcel ->getSheetByName("My Sheet1")->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $cellID = $drawing->getCoordinates();
        //  .... do your save here
    }
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: hey Gaurav, I am using Mattwebsite/excel package to import data from excel sheet but i am unable to store images per row
after using memorydrawing it gets all images at once and that too unordered

i have also posted a question, If you get a minute,kindly check.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70873603/importing-images-along-with-other-fields-username-subjectname-from-excel-in-la