# Importing images along with other fields (username,subjectname) from excel in laravel

Tags: excel, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I am using **phpspreadsheet.** I want to import an excel sheet that have images too, it looks something like this,
[image: Picture of excel sheet]

I am able to retrieve fields separately and images separately, I want to get them together. Problem I am facing is that Images are being accessed with

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection()
```

and for others field i have to access them like this

```
$spreadsheet->getRowIterator()
```

as both of them requires separate loops, should i be merging them into one or what is the right way so that i am able to retrieve both(images and fields) together.

**Images retrieve code:**

```
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($request->import_file);
$i = 0;

foreach ($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $key => $drawing) {


    if ($drawing instanceof MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        switch ($drawing->getMimeType()) {
            case MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_PNG :
                $extension = 'png';
                break;
            case MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_GIF:
                $extension = 'gif';
                break;
            case MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_JPEG :
                $extension = 'jpg';
                break;
        }
    } else {
        $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(), 'r');
        $imageContents = '';
        while (!feof($zipReader)) {
            $imageContents .= fread($zipReader, 1024);
        }
        fclose($zipReader);
        $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
    }

    $myFileName = time() .++$i. '.' . $extension;

$imagesCollection['answerImages_'.$key] =$myFileName;

    file_put_contents('images/products/' . $myFileName, $imageContents);

$a = Answers::create([
'answerImages'=>$myFileName,
'questionId'=>($key <=4)?1:2,
]);
}
```

I want to store them into my table in database such that in questionImage column of database it has image name like this

[image]

and it is storing it currently but as I mentioned earlier i have to store them separtely

**This is how i am storing other fields**

```
  $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($the_file->getRealPath());
           $sheet        = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
           $row_limit    = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
           $column_limit = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
           $row_range    = range( 1, $row_limit );
           $column_range = range( 'F', $column_limit );
           $startcount = 2;
           $data = array();
           foreach ( $row_range as $row ) {
               $data[] = [
                   'courseName' =>$sheet->getCell( 'A' . $row )->getValue(),
                   'subjectName' => $sheet->getCell( 'B' . $row )->getValue(),
                   'question' => $sheet->getCell( 'C' . $row )->getValue(),
                   'questionImage' => $sheet->getCell( 'D' . $row )->getValue(),
                
               ];
               $startcount++;
           }
           DB::table('questions')->insert($data);
```

How to get them together so that i can store them in one table

Answer (score 0):

you should try maatwebsite/excel package. it will save your time.

Comment: I have used that one too but mattwebsite/excel doesn't have anything about importing images in their documentation.